# why my rotate css isn't working when I try to change it while scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an h1 changing while scrolling down the page. I want a fixed position in the middle of the Y page at the left side. Why isn't fixed? The word curriculum is not where the others are

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("div")
const clientTag = document.querySelector("h1.client")

document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const pixels = window.pageYOffset
  
  sections.forEach(section => {
    if (section.offsetTop - 60 <= pixels) {
      clientTag.innerHTML = section.getAttribute("data-client")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  height:100vh;
}

header {
  display:inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(50%, 50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%,50%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 78% 100%;
  padding:auto;
  margin:auto;
  

}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="client">work</h1> 
</header>

<div data-client="work"></div>

<div data-client="about"></div>

<div data-client="curriculum"></div>

<div data-client="contact"></div>
```

Comment: By default, the center/origin of your CSS rotation is in the middle of the object. So if the text changes, it will recalculate the center of the rotation to the middle of the text. So if the text gets longer, the point of rotation moves to the right. You probably set `transform-origin` to something like `left center` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) is what makes the header jump around so much. You can remove it so it takes the default value (`center`) and is always rotated relative to it's center, which is defined by setting the `top` and `left` properties.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("div")
const clientTag = document.querySelector("h1.client")

document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  const pixels = window.pageYOffset
  
  sections.forEach(section => {
    if (section.offsetTop - 60 <= pixels) {
      clientTag.innerHTML = section.getAttribute("data-client")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  height:100vh;
}

header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="client">work</h1> 
</header>

<div data-client="work"></div>

<div data-client="about"></div>

<div data-client="curriculum"></div>

<div data-client="contact"></div>
```